# I can't kill skeletons

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I Have problems with killing the skeleton guys. How am I supposed to get my strength up enough to get through that if the overall strength just sucks? I am almost a Level 4 high elf.

Comment: What is it exactly you have problems with? Do they kill you within two blows or do you need to hit them 40 times? You can pretty much dodge and block there attacks and hit them between there attacks for maximum efficiency. What class are you playing anyway?

Comment: I don't know how you are trying to kill them but they are fully resistant to poison and paralysis and have a 25% resistance to frost. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skeleton

Comment: What skills are you focused on? I assume some kind of magic if you're a high elf but Level 4 High Elf doesn't tell us anything except you don't belong in Skyrim- it's the land of the Nords, damnit.

Comment: What's your gear, how do you fight them?

Comment: I assume you mean Draugr? because if you were struggling to kill skeletons you have the game difficulty set waaaayyyy to high for your playing ability skeletons will die in pretty much one hit as they are really brittle.

Answer (score 4):

Being that Skyrim is a fully explorable, non-linear sandbox. You could do an arguably infinite amount of things to improve your strength. I am gonna assume by your level/progression that you are playing either normal or higher and probably have no inclination to change your difficulty so on to the things you can do.

Explore the world, do side quests found through-out the world. This could easily take up 100+ hours and you would never touch the main questline. Eventually you will be level 40-60 and have no issues with most skeletons.